# delete file when user close the browser in java

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, browser

I want to delete file from server when browser closed at client side.

I have a requirement to save a an XML file and the same page will be reloaded using same XML after clicking submit button. To reload the same page JSP require the previously saved file. But I need to delete that file when it’s not required, is it possible to delete the file when browser closed, as I am not supposed to use sessions, how to find when user is closed the browser. I am using Spring MVC framework.

Please give me any idea how can I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax to make this possible :

```
1:Check if user wants to exit the window 
2: if yes then make Synchronous ajax call to a file that contains code to delete a file
```

example :-

```
    $(window).unload( function () {

    $.ajax({
       url: "page_which_contains_file_deletion_code.jsp",
       success: function(data){
         alert("File Deleted Successfully");
       },
     async: false
     }); 
});
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the AJAX call will be made, given the fact that the browser is being closed?

Comment: I have another problem, window.unload event will executed when user clicks submit button, Is there any way to find which unload it is whether user submitted or closed window, because file should be deleted only when window closed.

Thanks in advance.